# CMake & "PATH" Variables

Tags: cmake

In CMake, how do I define a PATH-type cache variable that (in Windows,  `cmake-gui.exe`) gives me the little "..." button to get the Popup dialog?  Right now, I'm using syntax like:

```
SET(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR "something" CACHE PATH "Location of libraries")
```

But it seems to treat it as a String.

Update:

Here's an explicit example:

```
IF(EIGEN_DIR)
    SET(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS ${EIGEN_DIR} CACHE PATH "Location of the Eigen include files")
ELSE()
    SET(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS "" CACHE path "Location of the Eigen include files")
ENDIF(EIGEN_DIR)
```

And `EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS` winds up as a String, even upon a fresh first-time run of CMake.

Comment: When I try this very line, it works perfectly fine. Did you try to remove `CMakeCache.txt` and to generate again?

Comment: Yes, it's in the CMakeLists.txt file that I use from scratch on a first configure, and it treats them all as Strings.  I'm using 2.8.10.

Comment: I just added a couple more ideas to my answer.

Comment: You can also try to add FORCE, it causes the variable to be overwritten when you change something, without having to delete the cache manually.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is correct.

However, it appears that to change the type of a variable, you need to close cmake-gui.exe, delete the variable from CMakeCache.txt (or delete the whole file), then reopen cmake-gui.exe

Another possibility is that you `set` the same value earlier to `STRING` type (in which case the first type is kept):

```
SET(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR "something" CACHE STRING "Location of libraries")
SET(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR "something" CACHE PATH "Location of libraries")
```

or else you `unset` the same value later and `set` it to a different type:

```
SET(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR "something" CACHE PATH "Location of libraries")
UNSET(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR CACHE)
SET(LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIR "something" CACHE STRING "Location of libraries")
```

Comment: For some reason, that's not working.. Specifically:  

    IF(EIGEN_DIR)
 SET(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS ${EIGEN_DIR} CACHE PATH "Location of the Eigen include files")
    ELSE()
 SET(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS "" CACHE path "Location of the Eigen include files")
    ENDIF(EIGEN_DIR)

And EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS is still only a String, not a Path. (Sorry for the formatting, I can't figure out SO's comment formatting fubarness)

Comment: In your `ELSE` part, you have `CACHE path` rather than `CACHE PATH`.  That could be the cause.